# Is it possible to use `Log In with PayPal` to make REST api requests on behalf of the user?

Tags: oauth, paypal

We've successfully integrated [Log In with PayPal (formerly PayPal Access)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/) however we would like to make [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers) requests on behalf of the authenticated user (with their permission).

The scopes available for the `Log In with Paypal` OAuth service make no mention of Rest API. Basically what we would like to do is import transactions and payment information from our authenticated users paypal account, into our system.

The documentation for the [Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) seems to imply that if we wanted to this, we would have to require our users to create an application themselves and provide us with the consumer key and consumer token.

I'm hoping someone on SO has done something similar and can point me in a more realistic direction. The [Classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/) seems like it could be a possiblilty, but we can't find any documentation regarding support for OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not available "yet". It's something in the works but unfortunately no date on the release yet.

Comment: hey @Praveen what would be the best way to retrieve transaction data on behalf of a user, other than asking them for their username and password?

Comment: with rest apis it's not possible yet. This is something in the APi but as you might have seen, we are slowly building out the capabilities in REST. Until then the only way you can achieve this is by using our classic permissions service (Oauth1.0a). Look here for information (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) - what you need are the Transaction search and details permissions.

Comment: @Praveen, is there any new development on this?  I've seen a lot of new API calls in the REST API, but I still can't find a way to make API requests on behalf of another user. Thanks

Comment: @RaduCugut You might find an answer in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577763/rails-with-paypal-permissions-and-paypal-express-checkout/32869517

Comment: @Praveen how can I contact you?

Comment: @Praveen Is it possible yet to use only the REST API (and Login with PayPal) to get permission from and perform an express checkout for another merchant?